# MS Excel:Select only cells of numbers containing meaningful decimal points

Tags: excel, numbers, decimal, selection

I have a spreadsheet with two kinds of elements: these include real numbers that aren't integers and integers. I want to select all numbers with decimal points i.e. 3.1415. I don't want to highlight cells that are whole numbers like 314. How do I do this custom selection?

I've tried conditional formatting and superuser.

Is there any way I can do this in a programming language like R?

Comment: What is the purpose of the Selection? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Edit number of digits after decimal points of only selected cells

Comment: Please try to make us understand what you want to achieve. Select and Highlight are two different things. Edit is yet another thing. Do you want to change the visible digits or actually edit the numbers? Please spend a few words, because on the internet we can't read your mind or see your screen, so please use your words.